# Compare Sunday to previous Sunday

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using SQL, and I want to compare latest Sunday views, to one Sunday views before that (for example: compare 1/9/19 to 25/8/19).

how should I do that?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. (And take a look at [mcve] before you start.)

Comment: Also, define "view". I can think of many different kinds of things you can mean, especially in an SQL environment.

Comment: using AWS redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Use dateadd() to get the previous Sunday's date:

```
select dateadd(wk, -1, "09/01/2019")
```